# Need help solving a Vertica ODBC Windows VS Linux charset mismatch

Tags: php, odbc, vertica

We're having a bit of trouble developing our PHP application using Vertica. Since an image is worth a thousand words, let's say we have the current code:

```
if(PHP_OS == "Linux")
    $c = new PDOVertica("Driver=/opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so;Server=192.168.1.49;Port=5433;Database=flexgroup;", "user", "password");
else
    $c = new PDOVertica("Driver=Vertica;Server=192.168.1.49;Port=5433;Database=flexgroup;Server_CSet=UTF-8", "user", "password");

$sql = "SELECT NoClient, NomClient FROM tblclients ORDER BY NomClient";

$stmt = $c -> prepare( $sql );
$stmt -> execute();

while($res = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $res['NomClient'];
}
```

This straightforward piece of code works and outputs the name of our clients almost correctly (if anyone's curious, the PDOVertica class is a homemade wrapper we built to bypass a bug where PDO loses parameter values. It calls the corresponding ODBC functions).

Anyway, the problem comes with accented characters. In order to output them correctly on our development machines, which run windows, we have to do the following

```
echo utf8_encode($res['NomClient']);
```

Now this wouldn't be a problem if both production and development environments worked the same way... but of course, they don't. In production, using utf8_encode garbles the string and we instead have to do this for the same string to come out correctly:

```
echo $res['NomClient'];
```

The question is then very simple: Did anyone ever manage to solve this charset mismatch?

Thanks in advance,

Osu

EDIT: In response to sKwa, I did indeed know about the UTF-16/UCS-2 thing before posting. However, I made the mistake of assuming UTF-8 and UTF-16 were actually compatible... they aren't. Another mistake I made was when I changed my page's charset to ISO-8859-1 and was surprised to see everything magically display properly. The reason for this is that ISO-8859-1 and UTF-16 intersect as far as letters and numbers are concerned at least(I didn't check EVERY possible characters, mind you, so I'm sure somewhere, the two encodings will differ).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you need to work with UTF-16(or UCS-2) and not with UTF-8. Im not sure but I think that on Windows its UTF-16 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes)(depends on MS Windows version and system configuration)

[About Locales](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Locales/AboutLocales.htm)

> All input data received by the database server is expected to be in UTF-8, and all data output by HP Vertica is in UTF-8. The ODBC API operates on data in UCS-2 on Windows systems, and normally UTF-8 on Linux systems.